# Nginx - Upstream redirect not working

Tags: nginx, syntax

Hoping someone can point out my failing with my config.

I have an issue where my upstream redirect does not work as it should (must be a config issue) , it redirects from https to http, which I do not have running at the moment. Obviously I require my https server to only serve secure traffic and not redirect to http.

This is what I receive in my browser bar : 
http://nginx.dev1.whispir.net/tmpl/home.tmpl#!/web_com/View_Workspace?rd=1307

But I require it to go to upstream over https.

In the debug of the browser I see :
GET http://nginx.dev1.whispir.net/tmpl/home.tmpl net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Cannot fathom out why it is hitting port 80.
I have turned off http on port 80, as I require the https working.
I hope someone can help here, driving me insane.

thanks for looking.

This is my current config for port 443

```
upstream HttpsMainWorker {
        # Sticky session
        ip_hash;

    server 10.1.161.59:8080;
    server 10.1.161.56:8080;
 }

upstream HttpsReportWorker {
        # Sticky session
        ip_hash;

    server 10.1.161.64:8080;
 }

upstream HttpsApiWorker {
        # Sticky session
        ip_hash;

    server 10.1.161.51:8080;
 }

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         nginx.dev1.whispir.net;
    keepalive_timeout   70;


    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certs/2016/61d2d567aece769c.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/certs/2016/wildcard.dev1.whispir.netclear.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout     5m;

    ssl_protocols   TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers     ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    access_log          /var/log/nginx/app17web/access.log  main;
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/app17web/error.log  debug;

    root                /data/htdocs/app17web.dev1.whispir.net;
    index index.jsp;

    rewrite_log on;
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|pdf)$ {
    expires 1d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    error_page 401      /401.html;
    error_page 403      /403.html;
    error_page 500 502  /500.html;
    error_page 503      /503.html;
    error_page  400 404       /404.html;
    location  = /404.html {
        internal;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

  location /{
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }



location @backend {
    proxy_pass  http://HttpsMainWorker;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }

    location ~ \.jsp$ {
        proxy_pass                      http://HttpsMainWorker;
        proxy_next_upstream             error timeout invalid_header http_500;
       proxy_connect_timeout    5s;

    }


    location /ivr/ivrRequest.ivr {
        proxy_pass                      http://HttpsMainWorker;
        proxy_next_upstream             error timeout invalid_header http_500;
       proxy_connect_timeout    5s;

    }

    location  /app/cfu/* {
        proxy_pass                      http://HttpsMainWorker;
        proxy_next_upstream             error timeout invalid_header http_500;
       proxy_connect_timeout    5s;

    }

    location  /tmpl/* {
       proxy_pass                      http://HttpsMainWorker;
        proxy_next_upstream             error timeout invalid_header http_500;
       proxy_connect_timeout    5s;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the upstream application (running on port 8080) is issuing the redirect. Either it needs to be configured to use `https` in a redirect, or it needs to be informed that the frontend connection arrived over `https`.

Your configuration inserts a header `X-Forwarded-Proto` for that purpose, but only for one of the `locations`.

The `proxy_set_header` directive is inherited from the outer block, **only if** no other `proxy_set_header` directives are set in the `location`.

So, either add a `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` statement into each affected `location` block, or move **all** of your `proxy_set_header` directives into the `server` block scope.

For example:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

location @backend {
    proxy_pass  http://HttpsMainWorker;
}
location ~ \.jsp$ {
    proxy_pass                      http://HttpsMainWorker;
    proxy_next_upstream             error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    proxy_connect_timeout    5s;
}
location /ivr/ivrRequest.ivr {
    proxy_pass                      http://HttpsMainWorker;
    proxy_next_upstream             error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    proxy_connect_timeout    5s;
}
location  /app/cfu/* {
    proxy_pass                      http://HttpsMainWorker;
    proxy_next_upstream             error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    proxy_connect_timeout    5s;
}
location  /tmpl/* {
    proxy_pass                      http://HttpsMainWorker;
    proxy_next_upstream             error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    proxy_connect_timeout    5s;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for details.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for the quick response, it worked like a charm, really appreciate this. Big Thanks.